# No apk created while building in phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

Beginner in phonegap here the steps I did and get a problem:

```
> npm install -g phonegap (I already have node.js) 
> phonegap create my-app 
> cd my-app 
> phonegap build android 
[phonegap] executing 'cordova build'... 
[phonegap] completed 'cordova build'
```

--> But no platforms/android/bin directory created which is assumed to contain the apk created

using `phonegap build android --verbose`
I have this at the end:

```
C:\Users\hmeknassi\Desktop\test\my-app>goto end
C:\Users\hmeknassi\Desktop\test\my-app>set _JAVACMD=
C:\Users\hmeknassi\Desktop\test\my-app>set ANT_CMD_LINE_ARGS=
C:\Users\hmeknassi\Desktop\test\my-app>if "Windows_NT" == "Windows_NT"
C:\Users\hmeknassi\Desktop\test\my-app>if "Windows_NT" == "WINNT"
C:\Users\hmeknassi\Desktop\test\my-app>if exist "\antrc_post.bat" call "\antrc_post.bat"
Built the following apk(s):


Command finished with error code 0: C:\Users\hmeknassi\Desktop\test\my-app\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat

[phonegap] completed 'cordova build android --verbose'
```

Any idea what is the problem ? or some advice to detect it ...

Thanks

Comment: `phonegap platform add android` THEN `phonegap build android`

Comment: Nothing, it says that android is already added and `phonegap build android` gives the same result:
`>phonegap platform add android`
`Platform android already added`

Comment: Do you have `ant` installed and set in your `PATH`?

Comment: Thanks ! you were right ! I was using a modified version of ant!

Answer (score 0):

```
phonegap create foldername com.package.name ProjectName
cd foldername
phonegap platform add android
phonegap build android
```

you need to keep your html files in **foldername/www** folder

after your build your apk will be in *foldername/platforms/build/outputs/apk*

I hope it helps. Thanks